# Write code once and add a referral to when I want to run it again?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, tic-tac-toe

Is there any way I can write a code once and then if I want to run the same line(s) of code again I could just add another line referring to the previous?

Ex:
Checking for wins in a Tic Tac Toe game.

- Enter code to check for wins.
- After each turn is complete (using a JButton) run the same check
  code again.

Answer (score 3):

Put the repeated lines of code into a separate method, then simply call that method whenever you need to check for wins.

This could be something along the lines of:

```
public boolean checkForWins() {
    // perform your checking here
}
```

When the turn is complete, you can refer to this code like so:

```
if (checkForWins()) {
    // what to do if there is a win
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a static method which you call after each turn.